The finite axioms of NBG set theory.
I've seen from various sources that NBG can be written with finitely many axioms.
But I've been struggling for a while to find a list of these axioms, every list I can find uses an axiom of schema in one form or another. Example nlab uses a schema for Class comprehension. My question is what are the axioms of NBG without using a schema.

Refrain from adding links, this forces viewers to click in the link to understand your question.

The comprehension schema can be replaced with a finite number of instances, known as the Gödel operations. Jech covers this, albeit in the guise of axiomatizing $\Delta_0$-comprehension for transitive models of ZFC, but a slight modification gives a proof that NBG is finitely axiomatizable.

Smullyan, Set Theory and the Continuum Problem uses NBG and describes the axioms (and also provides the proof alluded to by spaceisdark green above).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory

It's also covered in Mendelson's Introduction to Set Theory.
